# Ionic 3 app receives background notifications as expected from FCM web interface, but not with curl

Tags: android, curl, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic3, cordova-plugin-fcm

I have included FCM from Ionic Native, and I can receive notifications in the background and the foreground when I send a message from the FCM web interface.  It works as expected.  However, when I `curl` the request it only works in when the app is in the foreground.  Does anyone know why this would be? I didn't see anything [http protocol docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref).

Here is the request that I am sending.

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization:key=<fcm server key>"  -X POST -d '{ "data": { "title": "wow", "msg": "hello world"},"to":"<fcm token>"}' https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

I also tried to mimic the network traffic from the FCM web interface to see if it had to do with the payload fields, but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I found what I was looking for.  In order for the notification to show up when the app is closed, or running in the background, the `notification` object must exist in the payload.  For me, it had to have either a title or a body field as well.